# Solver equivalent in Progress / Python

Tags: python, math, formula, solver, progress-4gl

In Excel I have following formula:

```
=(B11* (1-(1 / (1 + ((100-B8)/200)))^B14)/((100-B8)/200)) + (100*(1 / (1 + ((100-B8)/200)))^B14)
```

I know result of this equation, say it is 150. I also know value of B11 and B14. They are constant.

I need to find out what B8 is.

In Excel I use Solver to calculate B8 and it is able to do it without any problems.

Is there way to calculate B8 in Progress or Python?

Thanks!

Comment: Couple of ideas. You can try solving it numerically; I think there is probably a one-dimension root finder in Scipy or Numpy. You can also try the bisection method. Another approach is to solve it symbolically; if that works you would have an expression you can paste into a program. Take a look at Sympy.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root_scalar.html